# Aurasma does not release audio resources

Tags: iphone, augmented-reality, android-audiomanager, aurasma

I am writing an iphone application where I use also Aurasma sdk for augmented reality. The application for other things use the microphone. At beginning the microphone work fine. If I call Aurasma and then return, the audio resource are not released form Aurasma (and the microphone does not work properly). Do you have any idea how fix this problems? Of course we already call [audioManager stopAudioRecording] before launch aurasma and [audioManager startAudioRecording] when returning from the aurasma.